# How to do jest testing in react native?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a simple code which I have written to test.

This is my App.js:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  function sum(a, b) {
     alert(a + b);
     return a + b;
  }

  return (
     <>
        <Button
          title="Sum"
          onPress={() => {sum(1,2)}}
        />
       
  );
```

This is my App-test.js in the `__tests__` folder:

```
import 'react-native';

const sum = require('../App');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

When I run `npm test` I get this error `TypeError: sum is not a function`. Can anyone help.

Note: When I run it on my android phone it works properly and shows 3 in the alert box.

Comment: you seem to be missing the closing `</>`. does it work after you added it?

Comment: where is the closing required

Comment: No it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are importing `sum` from your `App` file but it is not an exported method the way you wrote it.

You can do something like this:

```
export const sum = (a, b) => {
   alert(a + b);
   return a + b;
}

export const App = () => (
   <Button
      title="Sum"
      onPress={() => {sum(1,2)}}
   />
);
```

And use it like this in your test file:

```
import { sum } from '../App'

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

It's not particularly linked to React Native since you're only trying to test a specific method, which can be use with any framework.